# What does Ahlfors mean in this example evaluation of a definite integral via residues?

Tags: complex-analysis

On page 129 of Ahlfors, Complex Analysis, the author introduces the following integral $\int_0^{\infty} x^{\alpha} R(x) dx$, and presents two approaches to computing it via residues.

First, he makes the substitution $x = t^2$, and computes $\int_0^{\infty} t^{2 \alpha+1} R(t^2) dt$ via residues using "a closed curve consisting of two line segments along the positive and negative axis and two semicircles in the upper half plane, one very large and one very small."

Then, on page 130, he says that one can also compute directly (without substitution) using the closed curve shown in Fig. 26.  He comments: "This method needs some justification, for it does not conform to the hypotheses of the residue theorem.  The justification is trivial."

What does he mean by these comments?  I fail to see how the second method is materially different from the first.